# Old questions with missing users

Tags: discussion

I've seen quite a few old questions that share some common denominators.

- Question approximately 1+ year(s) old.
- NO answer
- Little to no comment interaction with questioner
- User has not logged in since the question and has only a single point.
- User is not a member of other stack exchange sites

Here is an [example](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/9455/2000-road-king-stalls-from-1st-2nd-gear) of the questions type that I am refering to.

**Under these particular circumstances does it make sense to close the question out?**

I am of the mind that it does make sense as some of these lingering questions that are enumerated by search engines send recipients of these links to this site and they get nothing out of it as the question is still opened.  I see the open questions under these specific circumstances and contamination of the site.

Comment: Can you answer that question, Ducati? I mean, I can't. The question isn't even a year old (almost though). I'm sure there are actually a ton of questions sitting in the background which are in the shape you are talking about though. I agree we should get rid of them if they are in excess of a year old and with the prereqs you've talked about. Just doesn't make sense. If a user comes back, they can add another question of the same ilk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds as though some of these questions are borderline for being deleted by the system anyway.

Looking at the [deletion guide on SE.Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) any post that no longer adds anything to a site should be deleted.

Each question should be assessed on its own merits but a tidy-up would not harm us.

Comment: I would agree with that 100% ... Let's get rid of some dead weight.

Comment: I wasn't able to read the linked question, but I agree that old questions without answers should be deleted. It *might* be appropriate to ask a question for more information in a comment, but given the nature of MVM&R, I doubt the user will come back to respond. #9 in the deletion guide will probably come into effect for many questions here, but manually cleaning up is never a bad thing.